# doxygen - ingroup a whole file including members?

Tags: doxygen

How do i group all the functions, classes, defines etc of a file?

Example file:

```
/*!
 * \file
 * \ingroup myGroup
 */

/*!
 * this is my function.
 */
int myfunc();
```

Now, if look at the output, only the file is added to that group. The function is not. i need to add `\ingroup myGroup` to that file to add it. Can that be done by brackets{} or any way else?

Comment: did you have a look at \{ and \} ?

Comment: yes, i allready wrote that. I tried it but it did not work. Maybe i got the wrong syntax. Do you have a working example?

Comment: I missed the \{ \} as the didn't show up clearly in your questions, there are just {}. You probably need to define the group with \defgroup (see documentation) and add \{ on the next line after the \defgroup. at the end of the file you will need a comment block with \}

Comment: @albert: the group is defined elsewhere. I cannot use \defgroup twice, can i? At least i should not...

Comment: Easiest way is trying it with a small test example (just did it and it is possible, but be aware about that group titles have to match).

Comment: Thanks to your persistence i found a working way. I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Thans to alberts persistence i found a working way:

```
/*!
 * \file
 * this is my testfile
 * \ingroup UnitName
 * \addtogroup UnitName
 * \{
 */

/*!
 * this is my function.
 */
int myfunc();

/*! \} */
```

This generates the wanted output. The File andthe function is added correctly.

It does not work with `\ingroup`. It puts the function into the files section (i upgraded to the latest version of doxygen with the same outcome.

Comment: This does work, but it does not work if you want to add functions to multiple groups. :(

Comment: Do you have to use `\ingroup` and `\addtogroup` simultaneously ? Wouldn't `\addtogroup` be enough ?